# PHPUnit prophesize a method without exact arguments

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, prophecy

I'm mocking a UserRepository class using [prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) to ensure that when a `POST` request to `/user` is sent, that the `create()` method on UserRepository is fired.

```
$repository = $this->prophesize(UserRepository::class);

$repository->create()->shouldBeCalled()
```

The only problem is that the `create()` method sends Request data as an argument to the repository for some serious tweaking of the inputs before doing anything. How do I mock the `create()` call without telling prophecy what the arguments will be?

Or is this just really bad practice on my end and the Request data should never be passed to the repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use Prophecy\Argument;

$repository->create(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use Prophecy\Argument;

$repository->create(Argument::cetera())->shouldBeCalled()
```

`any()` matches any *single* value where `cetera` matches *all* values to the rest of the signature.